# how to find total of only one column in python pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

My data i get from excel like;

```
Invoice Cost centre Invoice Category Price DataFeed Reporting Fequency
RIM                  Retail QLD      22.25  WEB      DWM
R5M                  Retail SYD      22.25  BWH      M
.....
```

my pivot table is like;

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Invoice Details', usecols="E:F,I,L:M")                       

df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)                                                                
df1 = df.groupby(["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"]).agg({'Price': 'sum'}).reset_index()      

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"],                             
                    columns=['Price', 'Reporting Frequency', 'Data Feed'],                             
                    aggfunc=len,                                                                       
                    fill_value=0)                                                                      

df2 = df.merge(df1, left_on=["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"],                               
               right_on=["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"], how='left').fillna(0)
```

[image]

I want to add total value for **price column only.** How can I do that in pivot table?

Expected output shouild be like;

```
Invoice Cost Centre  Invoice Category (22.25,M,BWH) (40,DWM,WEB)...     Price
           D3TM        Retail QLD                                     1907.85
          EQUITYEMP     Retail SYD                                    104.00
           EQUITYEMP                                                   463.15
           EQUITYEMP       ...                                         62.40
           EQUITYEMP                                                   201.95

                                                               **Total=2800**
```

Comment: Try to add some example data and expected output based on your example data. This way we can visually see what you want to do. Adding things like `pd.read_excel` or a picture of your data does not add any value to your question. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) thread.

Comment: not really following your logic, in terms of having a price only column your first groupby should do the trick?

Comment: @Erfan added more data to my question

Comment: @Datanovice I have provided more info. DOes that make sense?

Comment: Not really it doesn't make much sense to me atmo