# how to find last cell's index in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write string text in my outputs excel file;
My dataframe output is;

```
   Cost Centre     Category .. Price
    AQM             R1          10
    BQM             R2          100
```

Im writing this output to an excel;

```
 df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Invoice Summary',  index=False)
```

I would like to add sum value at the end of price column using worksheet write function

```
 worksheet = writer.sheets['Invoice Summary'']
      text='Total'
        total = sum(df2['Price'] )  
         worksheet.write(1, 0, text)
```

To do this, i want to know the row, column value of the last cell.
How can I find that in python?

Comment: what is worksheet? that isn't a `pandas` object.

Comment: @aws_apprentice yes pandas object, im writing the output to the excel sheet

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Be sure to show how all variables are initialized. Also double check your code example for compiler errors and use correct indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the worksheet.write function is just using row and column numbers and not Excel addresses, you could simply use `df2.shape` to get the total number of rows and columns in your dataframe. Since you are excluding the index column, the position at after the end of the price column would be `(df2.shape[0] + 2, df2.shape[1] - 1)`

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted. DO you know answer for these 2 questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59383476/how-to-find-total-of-only-one-column-in-python-pandas-pivot-table   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367985/after-merging-i-miss-pivot-table-columns-in-pandas